# How do I collect a loop through a list from http in JSON

Tags: flutter

I'm learning Flutter, but I've been a dev for a while now. I'm using one of my sites to make it headless, and trying to feed the data into my app.

I'm following the example: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

In this example, they fetch a single user. I'm a bit lost on how this would change if there were multiple users.

For example, if the data was structured more like:

```
{'users':[{'userId':1,'id':1,'title':'title1','body':'This is Body 1'},{'userId':2,'id':2,'title':'title2','body':'This is Body 2'}]
```

How could you capture that using the method in the tutorial? How could you loop through the list and display something simple like the title and bodies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the example from the tutorial, you could do this:

```
class Users {
  final List<Post> users;

  Users({this.users});

  factory Users.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    List<Post> tempUsers = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < json['users'].length; i++) {
      Post post = Post.fromJson(json['users'][i]);
      tempUsers.add(post);
    }
    return Users(users: tempUsers);
  }
}
```

And this is the Post class from the tutorial:

```
class Post {
  final int userId;
  final int id;
  final String title;
  final String body;

  Post({this.userId, this.id, this.title, this.body});

  factory Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Post(
      userId: json['userId'],
      id: json['id'],
      title: json['title'],
      body: json['body'],
    );
  }
}
```

To show a list of titles and bodies, you could change the FutureBuilder on the tutorial like this:

```
final Future<Users> users;
```

...

```
FutureBuilder<Users>(
  future: users,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: snapshot.data.users.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Title: ${snapshot.data.users[index].title}'),
              Text('Body: ${snapshot.data.users[index].body}'),
            ],
          );
        },
      );
    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Text("${snapshot.error}");
    }

    // By default, show a loading spinner.
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  },
),
```

---

I recommend you this article to learn more about parsing JSON: 
[Parsing complex JSON in Flutter](https://medium.com/flutter-community/parsing-complex-json-in-flutter-747c46655f51)

Also, here you can find more information about how to do manual serialization and automated serialization: 
[JSON and serialization](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json)

Comment: I'm getting the error:
Compiler message:
lib/main.dart:59:23: Error: Final field 'users' is not initialized.
Try to initialize the field in the declaration or in every constructor.
  final Future<Users> users;

Comment: You should change this.post for this.users in the constructor of MyApp, then change post for users on the call of MyApp in runApp and also you will need to return a Future<Users> in fetchPost() using a mock response maybe instead of the api used on the tutorial that has the JSON structure you proposed

Comment: I don understand how this.post works when it comes to the api call. I understand the serialization but, when i attempt to print out a test, it doesn't work.