# Json Data Comes Down But, Object Is Null

Tags: json, serialization, flutter, dart

I'm trying to pass the JSON data from my server into a premade object in Flutter but, I get a null value even though I passed the data to a variable and the corresponding class.

```
Future getPlaces() async{
  _isLoading = true;
  var url = 'http://Place-2212.herokuapp.com/api/customer/Locations/';

    http.get(url, headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  }).then((http.Response response)  {
    // print(response.body);

    final responseData = json.decode(response.body);


     Place place = Place.fromJSON(responseData);

    print(place.toJson());
    return Place;


  });

}
```

The output here is this:

```
 {id: null, name: null, address: null, city: null, placePhoto: null, state: null, lat: null, long: null, rating: null}
```

How do i get the data that pulls down from the json request into my object?

Update 1:

Here is how Place class is implemented:

```
class Place {
  int id;
  String name;
  String address;
  String city;
  String restaurantPhoto;
  String state;
  double lat;
  double long;
  String rating;

  Place({
    this.id,
    this.address,
    this.city,
    this.restaurantPhoto,
    this.lat,
    this.long,
    this.name,
    this.state,
    this.rating,
  });

  factory Place.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> json){
     return Place(
    id: json['id'] as int,
    name: json[‘restaurant_name'] as String,
    address: json['street_address'] as String,
    city: json['city'] as String,
    restaurantPhoto: json['restaurant_photo'] as String,
    state: json['state'] as String,
    lat: json['lat'] as double,
    long: json['lng'] as double,
    rating: json['rating'] as String,
  );
  }
}
```

Update 2: Here is the JSON response that I want to serialize.

```
{places: [{id: 4, place_name: The Oasis, phone: 123-123-1234, street_address: 456 Fake St, place_logo: https://restaurant.s3.amazonaws.com/restaurant_logo/restaurantLogo_jXon4qm.jpg, place_photo: https://restaurant.s3.amazonaws.com/restaurant_photo/farma.jpg, city: New York, state: New York, zip_Code: 12345, lat: 40.0, lng: 40.0, latlng: (40.7770112244898, -74.2110798163265), opening_hours: [], ratings: 3.0},
```

Comment: How Place.fromJSON method is implemented? What's the structure of the responseData map?

Comment: Updating code now

Comment: Added  place implementation

Comment: Could you post the response you are getting? So we can see if the structure of the JSON is according to what you are trying to parse

Comment: Updating code now.

Comment: I updated my answer with a full example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement the Place.fromJSON() according to the structure of the JSON you're receiving. Here you can see an example that could help you to achieve that: [how do I collect a loop through a list from http in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58290569/how-do-i-collect-a-loop-through-a-list-from-http-in-json/58290868#58290868)

---

**Edit:** From what I see in your Update 2, the JSON seems to be malformed, it needs to have quotation marks on the keys and on the string values. You could use this to try to structure the JSON correctly: [JSON Editor Online](https://jsoneditoronline.org/)

I assume the JSON structure you want to have is this one:

```
{
  "places": [
    {
      "id": 4,
      "place_name": "The Oasis",
      "phone": "123-123-1234",
      "street_address": "456 Fake St",
      "place_logo": "https://restaurant.s3.amazonaws.com/restaurant_logo/restaurantLogo_jXon4qm.jpg",
      "place_photo": "https://restaurant.s3.amazonaws.com/restaurant_photo/farma.jpg",
      "city": "New York",
      "state": "New York",
      "zip_Code": 12345,
      "lat": 40,
      "lng": 40,
      "latlng": "(40.7770112244898, -74.2110798163265)",
      "opening_hours": [],
      "ratings": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

Then, to parse this JSON you could do something like this:

```
final String jsonExample = '{"places":[{"id":4,"place_name":"The Oasis","phone":"123-123-1234","street_address":"456 Fake St","place_logo":"https://restaurant.s3.amazonaws.com/restaurant_logo/restaurantLogo_jXon4qm.jpg","place_photo":"https://restaurant.s3.amazonaws.com/restaurant_photo/farma.jpg","city":"New York","state":"New York","zip_Code":12345,"lat":40,"lng":40,"latlng":"(40.7770112244898, -74.2110798163265)","opening_hours":[],"ratings":3}]}';

void testExample() {
  final responseData = json.decode(jsonExample);
  PlaceResults placeResults = PlaceResults.fromJSON(responseData);
  print('$placeResults');
}

class PlaceResults {
  List<Place> results;

  PlaceResults({this.results});

  factory PlaceResults.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    List<Place> tempResults = [];

    for (int i = 0; i < json['places'].length; i++) {
      tempResults.add(Place.fromJSON(json['places'][i]));
    }

    return PlaceResults(results: tempResults);
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return results.fold("",(prev, element)=> '$element,$prev');
  }
}

class Place {
  int id;
  String placeName;
  String streetAddress;
  String city;
  String placePhoto;
  String state;
  num lat;
  num lng;
  num ratings;

  Place({
    this.id,
    this.streetAddress,
    this.city,
    this.placePhoto,
    this.lat,
    this.lng,
    this.placeName,
    this.state,
    this.ratings,
  });

  factory Place.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Place(
      id: json['id'],
      placeName: json['place_name'],
      streetAddress: json['street_address'],
      city: json['city'],
      placePhoto: json['place_photo'],
      state: json['state'],
      lat: json['lat'],
      lng: json['lng'],
      ratings: json['ratings'],
    );
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'id:$id,placeName:$placeName,streetAddress:$streetAddress,city:$city,placePhoto:$placePhoto,state:$state,lat:$lat,lng:$lng,ratings:$ratings';
  }
}
```

Notes:

- I'm using the type num instead of double for lat, lng and ratings
  since in your response example they are ints but I assume they could
  also be double, so using num will accept both cases
- I changed the name of the properties in the class Place to be the
  same as the name of the properties of the response, to avoid
  confusions
- I removed the castings like json['id'] as int, since it's not
  necessary
- I override the toString() methods in the classes just to print the example