# From "Future <RecetaList>" to "RecetaList" on Flutter

Tags: json, flutter

I am getting a json from a server, I receive all the data in that I have no problem, my problem arises once obtained  I can not pass it to my RecetaList class, I can only pass it to Future , is there any way to pass all the json to my class RecetaList.

> This is the method that rescues the information from the server, here
>   I have no problems:

```
Future<RecetaList> fetchFavoritos() async {
  final response =await http.get('https://recetas-inf422.herokuapp.com/');
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // Si la llamada al servidor fue exitosa, analiza el JSON
       return RecetaList.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  } else {
        throw Exception('Failed to load post');
  }
}
```

> Later in my class:

```
class _TrendingState extends State<Trending> {

      Future<RecetaList> recetado;
      RecetaList receta1;

      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        recetado = fetchFavoritos();
        receta1= fetchFavoritos(); //Aqui es donde me da un error
      }
    }
```

> The problem is presented here:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    recetado = fetchFavoritos();
    receta1= fetchFavoritos(); //  <-- This is where I get an error
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the `recetado` variable to fill your `ListView`, here is an example:

[how do I collect a loop through a list from http in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58290569/how-do-i-collect-a-loop-through-a-list-from-http-in-json/58290868#58290868)