# Get the lenght of a List<dynamic> in flutter

Tags: json, list, dictionary, flutter, dart

I'm working with a JSON like that:

```
{results: success, data: {total: 250, currentlyAvailable: 250, bestTimeToGo: 22, forecasts: [{hour: 21, available: 250}, {hour: 22, available: 24}, {hour: 23, available: 229}]}}
```

In flatter I decoded this JSON and I have casted the result in a MAP

```
var res = await http
    .get(Uri.encodeFull(link), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
if (res.statusCode == 200) {
  var data = json.decode(res.body);
  rest = data["data"] as Map;
  rest = rest["forecasts"]; //I have to work only with the "forecasts" section of the JSON
```

Now, I would like to know the lenght of this list of elements "rest", else I can't work with them.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List has [length](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.5.2/dart-core/List/length.html) property. So you should be able to do this:

```
final data = response["data"] as Map;
final forecasts = data["forecasts"];
print(forecasts.length);
```

Comment: No, I've already tried it, it is not declared as list, it is not a list but a map, if I try to get the lenght using this method I will get this error: (NoSuchMethodError: Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' has no instance getter 'lenght'.

Comment: Do you really need to reuse `rest` variable? I updated my answer...

Answer (score 1):

You could declare `rest` as dynamic, like this:

```
dynamic rest;
```

You can call any method on a `dynamic` typed variable. So you can get the length of `rest` with `rest.length` if `rest` is a list.

---

But it would be better to parse the JSON into an object. Here you have a quick example:

[how do I collect a loop through a list from http in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58290569/how-do-i-collect-a-loop-through-a-list-from-http-in-json/58290868#58290868)

Comment: Why this should give me a solution?

Comment: It was a var (so I think it is the same thing), but I updated my code and it still don't works: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast)

Comment: try to assign the forecasts directly to rest, without assigning the map to rest before, like this: rest = data["data"]["forecasts"]