# Fetch Json data flutter

Tags: json, flutter

i'm confusing with this kind of json.
because i never see someone explain about this kind of json data.

i get my jsondata from a link, and the json data show like this

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "jenis_komoditas": "Gabah IR 64 KP",
            "harga": "5400",
            "satuan": "Kg",
            "persen": null,
            "perubahan": "0",
            "selisi": "0",
            "image": "assets\/thumb\/gabah.png"
        },
        {
            "jenis_komoditas": "Gabah IR 64 KG",
            "harga": "6200",
            "satuan": "Kg",
            "persen": null,
            "perubahan": "0",
            "selisi": "0",
            "image": "assets\/thumb\/gabah1.png"
        }
    ]
}
```

it gets error.
can someone help me how to get the data from first json type?

Comment: I don't understand your question can you please state what is your problem and what you are trying to achieve? The corresponding code would also be very helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I collect a loop through a list from http in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58290569/how-do-i-collect-a-loop-through-a-list-from-http-in-json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse your full json string with

```
    Payload payload = payloadFromJson(jsonString);
    print('${payload.data[0].jenisKomoditas}');
```

Related Class

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final payload = payloadFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

Payload payloadFromJson(String str) => Payload.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String payloadToJson(Payload data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Payload {
    List<Datum> data;

    Payload({
        this.data,
    });

    factory Payload.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Payload(
        data: List<Datum>.from(json["data"].map((x) => Datum.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "data": List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Datum {
    String jenisKomoditas;
    String harga;
    String satuan;
    dynamic persen;
    String perubahan;
    String selisi;
    String image;

    Datum({
        this.jenisKomoditas,
        this.harga,
        this.satuan,
        this.persen,
        this.perubahan,
        this.selisi,
        this.image,
    });

    factory Datum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Datum(
        jenisKomoditas: json["jenis_komoditas"],
        harga: json["harga"],
        satuan: json["satuan"],
        persen: json["persen"],
        perubahan: json["perubahan"],
        selisi: json["selisi"],
        image: json["image"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "jenis_komoditas": jenisKomoditas,
        "harga": harga,
        "satuan": satuan,
        "persen": persen,
        "perubahan": perubahan,
        "selisi": selisi,
        "image": image,
    };
}
```

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final payload = payloadFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

Payload payloadFromJson(String str) => Payload.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String payloadToJson(Payload data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Payload {
  List<Datum> data;

  Payload({
    this.data,
  });

  factory Payload.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Payload(
    data: List<Datum>.from(json["data"].map((x) => Datum.fromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "data": List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}

class Datum {
  String jenisKomoditas;
  String harga;
  String satuan;
  dynamic persen;
  String perubahan;
  String selisi;
  String image;

  Datum({
    this.jenisKomoditas,
    this.harga,
    this.satuan,
    this.persen,
    this.perubahan,
    this.selisi,
    this.image,
  });

  factory Datum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Datum(
    jenisKomoditas: json["jenis_komoditas"],
    harga: json["harga"],
    satuan: json["satuan"],
    persen: json["persen"],
    perubahan: json["perubahan"],
    selisi: json["selisi"],
    image: json["image"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "jenis_komoditas": jenisKomoditas,
    "harga": harga,
    "satuan": satuan,
    "persen": persen,
    "perubahan": perubahan,
    "selisi": selisi,
    "image": image,
  };
}


void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  String jsonString = '''
  {
    "data": [
        {
            "jenis_komoditas": "Gabah IR 64 KP",
            "harga": "5400",
            "satuan": "Kg",
            "persen": null,
            "perubahan": "0",
            "selisi": "0",
            "image": "assets\/thumb\/gabah.png"
        },
        {
            "jenis_komoditas": "Gabah IR 64 KG",
            "harga": "6200",
            "satuan": "Kg",
            "persen": null,
            "perubahan": "0",
            "selisi": "0",
            "image": "assets\/thumb\/gabah1.png"
        }
    ]
}
  ''';

  void _incrementCounter() {
    Payload payload = payloadFromJson(jsonString);
    print('${payload.data[0].jenisKomoditas}');

    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          // Column is also a layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Invoke "debug painting" (press "p" in the console, choose the
          // "Toggle Debug Paint" action from the Flutter Inspector in Android
          // Studio, or the "Toggle Debug Paint" command in Visual Studio Code)
          // to see the wireframe for each widget.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Output

```
I/flutter (23421): Gabah IR 64 KP
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. but my code have solved before. but thank you verymuch

Answer (score 0):

you are getting data in form of json array so you can simply call it iteratively from the object. like this

if you get data in data variable:

```
final jsondata=json.decode(data);
for (var dataf in jsondata['data']){
  print(dataf['jenis_komoditas']);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. but it has solved before. thanks

Comment: If you have any query feel free to ask

Comment: @DhavalRank  help me in this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63751400/saving-local-json-data-to-model-class-and-fetching-to-view-elements-in-flutter.